# Processing an image to extract green-screen mask

Tags: python, performance, image, numpy, opencv

I am using OpenCV to process an image, and in my code, I have to check / edit each pixel separately:

```
import cv2, numpy

# we just use an empty image for the purpose of this MCVE
img = cv2.imread("source.jpg")   
width = len(img[0])
height = len(img)

empty_img = numpy.zeros((height, width, 3), numpy.uint8)

i = 0
r = 0
c = 0

for line in img:
    c = 0

    for pixel in line:
        blue = pixel[0]
        green = pixel[1]
        red = pixel[2]

        if green != max(red, green, blue) or green < 35:
            # this has a greenishy hue
            empty_img.itemset((r, c, 0), 255)

        c += 1
    r += 1
```

This code works, but is quite slow (it takes about 23 seconds to process the image). How could/should I speed this up?

source.jpg:
[image]

result should be:
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a simpler way to create the empty image using [`numpy.zeros_like`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.zeros_like.html):

```
empty_img = numpy.zeros_like(img)
```

As [Austin Hastings](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/106818/austin-hastings) correctly pointed out, the trick is to use vectorized operations provided by numpy:

```
RED, GREEN, BLUE = (2, 1, 0)

reds = img[:, :, RED]
greens = img[:, :, GREEN]
blues = img[:, :, BLUE]
```

---

```
mask = (greens < 35) | (reds > greens) | (blues > greens)
```

or, using [`numpy.amax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html)

```
mask = (greens < 35) | (numpy.amax(img, axis=2) != greens)
```

Now, one option is to use conditional indexing to modify `empty_img`. Since it's a 3 channel image (represented as 3 dimensional array), and our mask is only 1 channel (represented as 2 dimensional array) there are two possibilities:

- assign 3-tuples: `empty_img[mask] = (255,0,0)`
- provide the 3rd index: `empty_img[mask,0] = 255`

If all you care about is just a single channel mask, then [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is a possibility.

```
result = numpy.where(mask, 255, 0)
```

Answer (score 14):

Use conditional indexing:

```
RED, GREEN, BLUE = (2, 1, 0) # Your numbers

empty_img = numpy.zeros((height, width, 3), numpy.uint8)

reds = img[:, :, RED]
greens = img[:, :, GREEN]
blues = img[:, :, BLUE]

empty_img[(greens < 35) | (reds <= greens >= blues)][BLUE] = 255
```

**Edit:**

```
empty_img[(greens < 35) | ((reds <= greens) & (blues <= greens))][BLUE] = 255
```

I was wondering if the compound relation would work. Sadly, not. This should. If it doesn't you can try composing it step by step - look at just the `greens < 35` case, then the `reds <=greens`, etc.

Comment: I get this error: `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

Comment: Curses! You'll have to break down the compound <= >= statement. Let me edit.

Comment: I get some result, but not the same as with my own code. I uploaded source and result images.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Might that have something to do with checking against the empty image?

Comment: @Mast I updated my question, I am checking against a real image, and filling in the result in the empty image.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Ok. It always takes me a while with numpy to figure out what's going on.

Comment: @AustinHastings this doesn't seem to work at all. Looks like assignment doesn't work. Doesn't matter what I put in, the image always stays black.

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be called something like `mask_img`?

Comment: @DanMašek great, thanks! That should be the answer. For my application it doesn't matter that it is blue (in fact white on black is better), so by just writing out the mask I shaved another 0.1s off.

Comment: @BartFriederichs No problem. I was just writing it up when you deleted the original on SO :D | There's one more problem with this answer: `green != max(red, green, blue)` means that `(green < blue) or (green < red)`

Answer (score 2):

It seems like assigning a value like in the answer from @austin-hastings doesn't work. I fiddled a bit more and found that just using his conditionals in a mask does work (the boolean is a little different, but that is besides the point):

```
mask = ((greens < 35) | (reds >= greens) | (blues >= greens)) * 255
```

this creates a single layer (one color) mask that I can write out to a file:

```
cv2.imwrite("result.jpg", mmask)
```

I guess using it as a blue colour is not hard, but not relevant for my application. (In fact, a white mask is even better)

Answer (score 1):

It may be a matter of preference, but considering the logic of identifying the green screen could be a better way of forming a mask. Usually, a green screen has high green values **and** low red values **and** low blue values. So, for an openCV BGR image a mask would be:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("source.jpg")
b, g, r = img[:, :, 0], img[:, :, 1], img[:, :, 2]
mask = (g > 100) & (r < 100) & (b < 100)
```

The inverse of the mask, if required, is:

```
inv_mask = ~mask
```

Comment: How would this integrate into OP's code?  Where would your two (or three) lines go, and how does this improve the performance?

Comment: I made a small edit to show how this replaces the OP's code. I haven't bench marked the performance, but I would expect several orders of magnitude improvement over the original. This is similar to the other answers but my point is more to do with the logic of identifying the background colour.